# Long term storage of water softener

Tags: water-softener

A water softener has been disconnected and stored indoors for a year. Unit was drained. About an inch of salt was left to dry in the holding container. Unit was not disassembled.

Can it be re-installed and used?

Kenmore Ultrasoft 100. One piece model, uses salt. [Manual](https://c.searspartsdirect.com/mmh/lis_pdf/OWNM/L0305125.pdf).

Comment: Make and model? Was it drained and the resin bed removed?

Comment: @DanielGriscom Kenmore Ultrasoft 100, drained but not disassembled. Edited question with more details.